# How to display count of query result

Tags: mysql

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
      {
        echo $row;
      }
```

This is my code and I have got error as below:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\smarty_framework\workloc\action_files\passAction.php on line 17
```

Comment: mysql_, mysqli_, fetch_row, fetch_array ??? what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing the actual query to mysqli_fetch_row, instead of the query result. Try changing it to this:

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `$row` will be an array.

Comment: Sure, so printf($row) might be nice to display the result, however this should get rid of the error that was received.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing sql query to [mysqli_fetch_row();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
{
   //your code
}
```

Change to this :

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
    // your code
}
```

**[See](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)** for more information

Also as per your title of your question "How to display count of query result" - You can use [mysqli_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to get the number of result your query return.

Like this :

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

//echo $count; /* This will display the count */

if($count > 0)
{

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
   {
       // your code
   }

}
```